# Ionic Capacitor can no longer produce a buildable iOS project, CompileAssetCatalog error

Tags: ios, ionic-framework, capacitor

Having intractable build issues with Ionic 6.5.0 / Capacitor 2.2.0

I made the app not long ago, but today it won't build. After much fruitless updating/cleaning/building I deleted the `ios` directory and re-added it.

`ionic cap add ios`
`ionic cap sync`

Updated, removed `DerivedData`, clean build, same error:

```
CompileAssetCatalog /Users/me/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/App-ayobzjywexbfvjdrynzhsnownnyr/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/App.app /Users/me/Projects//MyProject/ios/App/App/Assets.xcassets (in target 'App' from project 'App')
    cd /Users/me/Projects//MyProject/ios/App
    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/actool --output-format human-readable-text --notices --warnings --export-dependency-info /Users/me/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/App-ayobzjywexbfvjdrynzhsnownnyr/Build/Intermediates.noindex/App.build/Debug-iphoneos/App.build/assetcatalog_dependencies --output-partial-info-plist /Users/me/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/App-ayobzjywexbfvjdrynzhsnownnyr/Build/Intermediates.noindex/App.build/Debug-iphoneos/App.build/assetcatalog_generated_info.plist --app-icon AppIcon --compress-pngs --enable-on-demand-resources YES --filter-for-device-model iPhone10,1 --filter-for-device-os-version 13.5.1 --sticker-pack-identifier-prefix com.prosc.itineris.sticker-pack. --development-region en --target-device iphone --target-device ipad --minimum-deployment-target 11.0 --platform iphoneos --product-type com.apple.product-type.application --compile /Users/me/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/App-ayobzjywexbfvjdrynzhsnownnyr/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/App.app /Users/me/Projects//MyProject/ios/App/App/Assets.xcassets

2020-06-15 15:40:01.929 ibtoold[73405:1839106] DEBUG: Added to environment: {
    TMPDIR = "/var/folders/g8/hc3lzhqn75d1ms9dzt46s7nw0000gn/T/E2DC0A8E-13DD-4566-A0E9-59C812831E2A";
}
Command CompileAssetCatalog failed with a nonzero exit code
```

If I run this command from the terminal it appears to exit with a `255` status, no errors/warnings/notices.

I tried the recommended updates in XCode, but I'm seeing some errors in the Xcode prior to the failure:

- /Users/me/Projects/MyProject/node_modules/@capacitor/ios/Capacitor/Capacitor/Plugins/Network/Reachability.swift:207:4: Unexpected version number in 'available' attribute for non-specific platform '*'
- /Users/me/Projects/MyProject/node_modules/@capacitor/ios/Capacitor/Capacitor/Plugins/Permissions.swift:39:5: Switch covers known cases, but 'AVAuthorizationStatus' may have additional unknown values, possibly added in future versions
- /Users/me/Projects/MyProject/node_modules/@capacitor/ios/Capacitor/Capacitor/CAPBridge.swift:375:29: Coercion of implicitly unwrappable value of type 'String?' to 'Any' does not unwrap optional
- /Users/me/Projects/MyProject/node_modules/@capacitor/ios/Capacitor/Capacitor/CAPPlugin.m:6:17: Method definition for 'shouldOverrideLoad:' not found

I don't think these are causing the error, however. Any suggestions / insights?

Answer (score 1):

The solution was to update XCode to 11.5 by installing a new build from the App Store. My version of XCode was not installed from the app store.

After updating the additional XCode tools, this updated actool from 11.2.1 to 11.5

This had nothing to do with Ionic/Capacitor, building a totally new native iOS app was exhibiting the same error.